# Using Node.JS Over PHP in my next Web App Project?

Tags: php, web-applications, node.js

I'm a student and I'm planning to do freelance web app development to pay for tuition fees and all. I haven't had much experience in this field though I know how to code in PHP.

Today, I read a bit about Node.js and how amazing it is in dealing concurrent tasks and stuff. It looks pretty neat. Should I dig deeper into it and start using it in freelance projects?

OR, am I completely wrong in my understanding of the web app development(judging from my above query)?

Answer (score 8):

Everybody thinks their latest hip technology is awesome. Maybe node.js is, maybe it is not. But your clients will be more happy if you use technologies that are more mature.

If your goal is simply to play around with node.js, then you should do so with your own personal projects before unleashing it on paying customers.

The thing to remember is that technology is rarely the reason for success or failure for web projects. PHP, Rails, Python, ASP, whatever... It's your skills and understanding as a programmer / analyst that make all the difference.

Because this is subjective, I'll pretend you asked "Is PHP sufficient to power my potential future projects?"

The answer is: ***It most certainly is***.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely suggest learning more about it and messing around with it. It's always good to have another tool under your belt.

But would i suggest using it in your projects? If your application can really benefit from using it then yeah, you should totally be using it. But it all depends if that's the right tool for the job (you wouldn't use a screwdriver to hammer a nail).

Answer (score 2):

Dig into it.

But still use PHP for most of your small website projects.
It's easier to deploy, every webhost supports it.

With Node.js you'd need to deploy on a vps or one of the Node.js PaaS betas, which makes it difficult to hand off to most potential clients.